# How to set image width of jquery created content

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors, width, css

I am having troubles with setting the width of a thumbnail/image that is been created automatically with jquery.

This is the code of the jQuery file:

```
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                a.appendChild(span); 
                                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute('src',(entry.thumbnail ? entry.thumbnail.hqDefault : ''));
                span.appendChild(img);
                var em = document.createElement('em');
                span.appendChild(em);
```

You can see that a img is being created, which I can see on my html with firebug too, like this:

```
<a class="clip" style="cursor: pointer;">
<span>
<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/iN9a273LvaQ/hqdefault.jpg">
<em></em>
</span>
</a>
```

How can I assign this image o width, without effecting all the other images I have on my website? I can set a max-width at my stylesheet, but that changes all my images' size and I don't want that. I would be very happy if someone could help me out...

I looked at other styled elements in the code and I found this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.setAttribute('id', cfg.block+'Player');
            iframe.setAttribute('type', 'text/html');
            iframe.setAttribute('width', cfg.width);
```

(...)

```
    if(!this.cfg.width){
                    this.cfg.width = 200;
                }
```

I guess it has to be something like this, but it didn't work for me when I tried to do same, removing cfg and replacing it with `img`.

Comment: uhm... you are way over thinking this, how about instead of diving in the library, u show us what you are doing outside the library and tell us what you intend to achieve

Comment: Oh dude, I am not going to waste my time on you.

Comment: Well, by what is shown here, either you're editing a library that doesn't need editing, or you're not using jQuery. If you were using jQuery, `var span = document.createElement('span');` would be `var span = $("<span />")`

Answer (score 1):

add id attribute to the created image

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('src',(entry.thumbnail ? entry.thumbnail.hqDefault : ''));
img.setAttribute('id', 'myImage');
```

and in your styles

```
#myImage {width: 200px;}
```

Comment: I knew it was easy... Thank you very much Zefiryn!

Comment: except, that's still not jQuery

Comment: @SpYk3HH this doesn't need jQuery.  None of the OP's code is jQuery either - it's all pure JS.

Comment: I know, that's what I was pointing out in my first comment when he told me "Oh i'm not even gonna bother with you". Simply trying to point out, that if you're gonna advertise a question about jQuery, you might should at least know what jQuery is first

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the width directly on the image element:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = ...;
img.width = 200;
```

Note that there's almost never any need to use `setAttribute` on a DOM element, just set the desired property instead.

If it turns out that you can't modify the code that you quoted, but can access the DOM after, use this jQuery:

```
$('a.clip > span > img').attr('width', 200);
```

This will affect only those images that have been created with your original snippet.